# Sitecore Certification

Tags: training-certification

I am a newbie in the world of sitecore and planning to learn and earn its certification. Looking at the info available the certification for sitecore 10 isn't released yet and If i take it in a month or 2 it would for 9 version. So, do i wait until 10 version certification is released or shall I go ahead with current 9 version certification.

One more question, without real-time project experience can the certification be cleared (of-course I will try my best in getting my hands dirty if I get hold of a running instance/license)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently certification about Sitecore 10 is not present.
need to wait.
but if you pass sitecore 9 certification, it should be fine after you could make a 10.